# Calendar Module Shows Two Month Links

Tags: views

So I have a view of a calendar with some events listed on it.  I also have this calendar setup to be a block on a page.

The block is on www.example.com/subsite

When I click the block it takes me to the month view of the calendar at 
www.example.com/subsite/month

Now, on this view, there are tabs at the top of the calendar in the following order with their respective links:

Month - www.example.com/subsite/month
Month - www.example.com/subsite
Week - www.example.com/subsite/week
Day - www.example.com/subsite/day
Year - www.example.com/subsite/year

So... That second Month link is obviously wrong.  How do I get rid of it and/or change the title to Home?  If I make the Month view not show on the settings page, it removes the Month link that actually goes to the Month view.

Any help would be awesome, thank you.

Comment: Calendar module?

Comment: Yes, http://www.drupal.org/project/calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two tabs of Month came up in the first place don't make sense. It never happened to me. I would suggest to recreate this Calendar view, it's actually pretty easy if you "add view from template". (Consider you've installed the Calendar Module)

Make sure to select “A calendar view of the 'field_date' field in the 'node' base table.” on the list of views/add-template

Comment: This is what managed to fix the second month link.  Additionally, the month link was still wrong but that was because of the way the calendar module creates the month link.  If you have a page at example.com/subsite, you can't have your calendar structure be example/subsite/(day:week:month:year), it needs to be something else, otherwise your month link will link to example/subsite.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Quicktabs to create the tabs? If so, you can go to structure > Quicktabs > Configure > Edit. At the bottom of the page, you'll see that you can select your block. You could try checking "Hide the title of this block" for whichever block you are using.